# How can we generate OpenAPI files on Bazel?

Tags: openapi, bazel

We are migrating a Maven project to [Bazel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazel_(software)). In this project, we generated our [OpenAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAPI_Specification) documentation from Java annotations and using the `swagger-maven-plugin` as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputFileName>swagger</outputFileName>
        <outputPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/webroot</outputPath>
        <outputFormat>JSON</outputFormat>
        <resourcePackages>
            <package>com.example.package1</package>
            <package>com.example.package2</package>
        </resourcePackages>
        <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>resolve</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way to generate this file using a Bazel rule?

Comment: Yes you can just create bazel skylark file to define the custom rule. Then create a build file in your Bazel workspace to define the custom rule usage and finally invoke the bazel build example `bazel build :openapi_docs`.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69992972/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 0):

Note: While Bazel supports downloading and publishing Maven artifacts with *rules_jvm_external*, it does not directly support Maven-based plugins. Maven plugins can't be directly run by Bazel since there isn't any Maven compatibility layer.

Ref: *[Migrating from Maven to Bazel](https://bazel.build/migrate/maven)*

This means this Maven plugin will not work for a Bazel build

Instead, I would suggest you to go with following:
*[OpenAPI Generator Bazel](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-bazel)*

Also you can check:

- *[OpenAPI, Code Generation, Bazel, and Spring Boot](https://damuliu.medium.com/openapi-code-generation-bazel-and-spring-boot-e7a3603b3289)*
- *[OpenAPI rules for Bazel](https://github.com/meetup/rules_openapi)*